# POST request does not work on Postman

Tags: javascript, rest, postman, router

I am trying to programmatically get some information from my router using API calls, so I am testing them in POSTMAN. I already worked the authorization but when I try to get the near WIFI APs, the result of the call does not show. This is the response

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Scan Results</title>
    <script language="JavaScript">

        function scanEvent() {
            window.document.wlanScanPopup.scanAction.value = 1;
            window.document.wlanScanPopup.submit();
        }

        function onLoadScript() {
            setTimeout("window.location.reload();", 1500);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="onLoadScript()">
    <form action="/goform/wlanScanPopup" method="POST"
          name="wlanScanPopup">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img border="0" src="logo_new.gif" width="200"
                         height="31">
                </td>
                <td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                    <input type="hidden" name="scanAction"
                           value=0>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <INPUT TYPE="Submit" VALUE="Refresh"
                           ALIGN="Middle" onClick="scanEvent();">
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <table style="font-family: Helvetica;font-
                  size:14">
                    <tr bgcolor=#009639>
                        <th colspan=9>
                            <b>Nearby Wireless Access Points</b>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="#009639">
                        <th>Network Name</th>
                        <th>Security Mode</th>
                        <th>Mode</th>
                        <th>PHY Mode</th>
                        <th>RSSI</th>
                        <th>Channel</th>
                        <th>Bandwidth</th>
                        <th>BSSID</th>
                    </tr>
                    </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

What I can see here is that once the HTML is loaded it changes the value from the hidden input and submits. I am trying to send the request with the key scanAction and value 1 but nothing happens. Any idea how I can get his to actually submit and work? The request is http://192.168.0.1/goform/wlanScanPopup

Also I already checked in the router admin page and the scan is working.
Thanks

Comment: Edit: I set the request to POST and I added the key value in headers and in body and it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the request method to POST in Postman? By default it is GET, but the form in your html specifies method="POST" so make sure you do this in Postman as well.

Also, make sure you add the parameter `scanAction` with value `1` to the request's body -- not as an URL parameter.

Also, make sure you authorize your request correctly.

Comment: Yes I set it to POST and added the parameter, still wont work